UseContext is not a function
I'm trying to use the context that I created to a really simple shopping cart example, for that, I created some functions and when I try to use it inside of my component, the error pops up.
I'm actually a beginner when it comes to using Context API, so if anyone could help, I'd be really happy.
Here's my context
"use client";
import { createContext, useState, ReactNode } from "react";
import { ShoppingCartProviderProps } from "../types/ShoppingCartProvider";
import { ShoppingCartFunction } from "../types/ShoppingCartFunction";
import { ProductCartItem } from '../types/Product';

export const ShoppingCartContext = createContext({} as ShoppingCartFunction);

export function ShoppingCartProvider({ children }: ShoppingCartProviderProps) {
  const [cartItem, setCartItem] = useState<ProductCartItem[]>([]);

  function getItemQuantity(id: number) {
    return cartItem.find(item => item.id === id)?.quantity || 0;
  }

  function increaseItemQuantity(id: number) {
    setCartItem(currItems => {
      if (currItems.find(item => item.id === id) == null) {
        return [...currItems, { id, quantity: 1 }];
      } else {
        return currItems.map(item => {
          if (item.id === id) {
            return { ...item, quantity: item.quantity + 1 };
          } else {
            return item;
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }

  function decreaseItemQuantity(id: number) {
    setCartItem(currItems => {
      if (currItems.find(item => item.id === id)?.quantity === 1) {
        return currItems.filter(item => item.id !== id);
      } else {
        return currItems.map(item => {
          if (item.id === id) {
            return { ...item, quantity: item.quantity - 1 };
          } else {
            return item;
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }

  function removeFromCart(id: number) {
    setCartItem(currentItems => {
      return currentItems.filter(item => item.id !== id);
    });
  }

  return (
    <ShoppingCartContext.Provider value={{ getItemQuantity, increaseItemQuantity, decreaseItemQuantity, removeFromCart }}>
      {children}
    </ShoppingCartContext.Provider>
  );
}

How I'm getting the data from API:
export const getData = async () => {

  const res = await fetch('https://fakestoreapi.com/products?limit=5');
  
  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error();
  }

  return res.json();
};

And the component that I'm trying to render within the context
import { ShoppingCartContext } from "@/app/context/ShoppingCartContext";
import { getData } from "@/app/data/fetchData";
import { ProductCardDescType } from "@/app/types/Product";
import ProductCard from "@/components/ProductCard/ProductCard";
import { useContext } from "react";

export default async function Store() {
  const post = await getData();

  const { getItemQuantity } = useContext(ShoppingCartContext)

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Store</h1>
      {post.map((product: ProductCardDescType) => (
        <ProductCard key={product.id} {...product} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

Provider:
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import "./globals.css";
import NavBar from "@/components/NavBar/NavBar";
import { ShoppingCartProvider } from "./context/ShoppingCartContext";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Create Next App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <ShoppingCartProvider>
          <NavBar/>
          {children}
        </ShoppingCartProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

I wanna use it the context within the component, and then use the other functions that I created for it.

It would be really helpful if you can create a sandbox for it.

It seems you should include "use client" in your component where you use useContext()

It looks like a client vs server component issue.
Here's a link to where next.js docs clearly state that:

Since React context is not supported in Server Components, ...

The short version is that you are trying to import a "client" code into a server component.
Specficly this line:
 const { getItemQuantity } = useContext(ShoppingCartContext)

To solve this, you need to either:

mark the component using the "useContext" with "use client" and as a result change the way you call const post = await getData() since it's not a server component

Make the server component import some client component that wrap your provider.  since ClientComponent can use "useContext" you can render what you need in that component and pass the relevant data to the server component.


import ClientComponent from './client-component'
import ServerComponent from './server-component'
 
// Pages in Next.js are Server Components by default
export default function Page() {
  return (
    <ClientComponent>
      <ServerComponent />
    </ClientComponent>
  )
}

The important thing to remember is that server component is rendered on the server, therefore they don't have interactivity lifecycle Effects (useState(), useReducer(), useEffect(), etc)
